# Cannot get active element form template

Tags: javascript, angular

I've a simple component as following where I am trying to get reference to the active element from it's template.

```
export class SidebarComponent {
  @ViewChildren(RouterLinkActive) linkItems: QueryList<RouterLinkActive>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let activeLink = this.linkItems.find(item => item.isActive);

    console.log('Active link is');
    console.log(activeLink); //this is undefined
  }

}
```

And here is a simple template for above component.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/app/link1']" routerLinkActive="active"> Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/app/link2']" routerLinkActive="active"> Link 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is I am not getting the active element from the template even though the style is applied to the element with `active` class. The same code worked with angular v2 but breaked in angular v4. What should I do to get the active element in angular v4?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}

...

let isLinkActive = this.linkItems.toArray()[0].isLinkActive(this.router);

let activeLink = this.linkItems.find(item => isLinkActive(item));
```

I assume your check just happens too early (when `isActive` is not yet set)

See also the code in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/82417b3ca59aa2e5f41ee12db4cb18970b5b4f47/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts (lines 98, 108, 132)

Comment: It is always giving the first element from template with `rouerLinkActive` attribute present.

Comment: What do you get for `this.linkItems[1].isLinkActive(this.router);`?

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLinkActive' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, please try `this.linkItems.toArray()[1].isLinkActive(this.router);`

Comment: Not sure why but invoking another private method `hasActiveLinks()` seems to work for me.

Comment: It gives `function (link) { return router.isActive(link.urlTree, _this.routerLinkActiveOptions.exact); }`

Comment: I updated my answer. I missed that `isLinkActive()` returns a function, not a boolean.

Comment: I am getting this error for your updated answer `TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

Comment: What code line do you get this error from? Try also to add `toArray()` before `.find(...)`

Comment: This error is raised from @angular/core. `hasActiveLinks()` is working fine so I am going to use that one. And many many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Weird. . . . .  .

Comment: Sorry to bother again but this way it worked. 

`let isLinkActive = this.items.toArray()[0].isLinkActive(this.router);`

 `let activeLink = this.items.find(item => isLinkActive(item.links.first || item.linksWithHrefs.first))`